# export oracle query result set to excel sheet using python script in linux os

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to output the results of an oracle sql query into an Excel file (xls format not csv). I thought that my code (Below) should do this, but it is not generating the Excel file. Can you help me identify either why the below is not creating the export file, or give me some sample code that does correctly create an Excel export file?

```
import cx_Oracle
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

uid="XYNERGY_BGR"
pwd="Bangal0r3"
service="BGRDB"
db = cx_Oracle.connect(uid + "/" + pwd + "@" + service)
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from AGENT_MAIN")

workbook = Workbook('outfile.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    for c, col in enumerate(row):
        sheet.write(r, c, col)
```

Comment: Whats your Question/Issue?

Comment: Start with examples / tutorials that work and then work up to whatever you need in your code?

Comment: The `workbook` is not `saved` at the end.

Comment: Clarified language for native English speakers. Added Excel tag.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check with below code and let me know  if it works successfully.

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter import Workbook
import cx_Oracle
import datetime
from datetime import date

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('HOST', 'PORTNO', sid='BGRDB') 
    
db = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'XYNERGY_BGR', password='Bangal0r3', dsn=dsn_tns)
cursor = db.cursor()

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/Path/outfile.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


cursor.execute("select * from TABLENAME")
for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
         for c, col in enumerate(row):
                sheet.write(r, c, col)

workbook.close()
cursor.close()
```